# how to register SQL Table dependency for non dbo user

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-signalr, service-broker

We are trying to enable SQLTableDependency from .Net code using Non-DBO SQL user, Currently, it's throwing a permission exception "The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it  ".

```
    var connectionString = dataAccessManage.ConnectionStringToBroker;
    _tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<Plan>(connectionString, schemaName : "",executeUserPermissionCheck: false); ;
    try
    {
        _tableDependency.OnChanged += Plan_OnChanged;
        _tableDependency.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for receiving notifications...");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogsWritter.SendErrorToText(ex, errorLogConfiguration);
        _tableDependency.Stop();
        throw;
    }
```

We did some troubleshooting and found if we grand below permission for NON-DBO users it will work fine.

Permission -

```
ALTER
CONNECT
CONTROL
CREATE CONTRACT
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE QUEUE
CREATE SERVICE
EXECUTE
SELECT
SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS
VIEW DATABASE STATE
VIEW DEFINITION
```

The problem is these permission statements will not pass our security review.  We cannot authorize db_owner permissions, and cannot grant  ALTER, CONTROL, EXECUTE, and SELECT to the entire database (which is basically db_owner permissions).

So need to know the solution for enabling SQLTableDependency for limited permission user, Which passes our security review.

Comment: @MartinSmith Please check now

Comment: Create a stored procedure in dbo that adds the dependency for you and then give the user EXEC rights on that dbo  This probably won't work if you don't know the table name ahead of time, but that raises the question of why you need to have random users able to do dangerous DDL statements like this from an unprivileged client.  Also, why do you have the messagebroker and service-broker tags on this question?